# How to calculate the delta for the first and each subsequent second in one minute?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks something like this (~400.000 lines)
It has every second from 10 to 19 pm and they are duplicated a lot

| Time | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 6 |
| 10:00:00 | 5 |
| 10:00:00 | 2 |
| 10:00:00 | 4 |
| 10:00:01 | 6 |
| 10:00:01 | 2 |
| 10:00:01 | 9 |
| 10:00:04 | 4 |
| 10:00:04 | 5 |
| 10:00:04 | 1 |

I have a function that groups by time and takes away the first and last values from the same identifiers time

```
def test_last_first():
    df = pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv, usecols = ['Time', 'Value'], parse_dates=[0])
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.floor("1S", 0).dt.time
    g = df.groupby('Time', sort=False)
    out = (g.last()-g.first()).reset_index()
    out.to_csv(P_opcl_1min, index=False)
    print(df)
```

Can I use Pandas to make it so that for every 60 seconds the first value is always the first of 10:00:00 and the last one is calculated for each second, that is 10:00:00 - 10:00:01 10:00:00 - 10:00:02 10:00:00 - 10:00:03 and so on?

What would turn out something like

| Index | Value | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -2 | 10:00:00-10:00:00 |
| 2 | 3 | 10:00:00-10:00:01 |
| 3 | -5 | 10:00:00-10:00:04 |
| 4 | 5 | 10:01:00-10:01:00 |
| 5 | 3 | 10:01:00-10:01:01 |
| 4 | 8 | 10:01:00-10:01:03 |

The index and the time column are added for clarity, just a column with the calculation of functions is enough

Comment: Can you clarify the logic of what you are trying to do?  What is the output of your function ```test_last_first()```?  What is the logic to go from the function output to your desired output?

Comment: I want to get the cumulative delta of the value column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['10:00:00',    6],
    ['10:00:00',    5],
    ['10:00:00',    2],
    ['10:00:00',    4],
    ['10:00:01',    6],
    ['10:00:01',    2],
    ['10:00:01',    9],
    ['10:00:04',    4],
    ['10:00:04',    5],
    ['10:00:04',    1],
    ['10:01:00',    1],
], columns=['time', 'value'])
data = df[pd.to_datetime(df.time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.second == 0].groupby('time').agg("first").reset_index()
data["hour_and_min"] = pd.to_datetime(data.time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
res = df.groupby('time').agg("last").reset_index()
res["hour_and_min"] = pd.to_datetime(res.time,format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.strftime("%H:%M")
pd.DataFrame(pd.merge(res, data, on="hour_and_min").apply(lambda x: [x.value_x - x.value_y, f"{x.time_y}-{x.time_x}"], axis=1).tolist(), columns=['value', 'time'])
```

output:

```
    value   time
0   -2  10:00:00-10:00:00
1   3   10:00:00-10:00:01
2   -5  10:00:00-10:00:04
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time' Even when I use parse_dates=[0]

Comment: I figured out the error in csv the column is called Time and it was passed in your code time
But for some reason I have unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' end 'str' is called if the csv file is done in the last line

Comment: Everything works thanks I fixed everything there my mistakes were stupid !

Comment: In csv, there are minutes where the 17:12:00 second is skipped, for example, I know it is selected by the command .dt.second == 0. I tried to interfere with for loops and or operators, but I can't get it to use even those minutes in the final frame where the zero second is skipped. Can you tell me what to do please?

Comment: @Show_man in fact, I didn't understand what you mean... please add your input example with desired output